# How can I change text with a button onClick 1 and then revert onClick 2?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I can get the text to change easily just once but I want to know how I can change it back to the original text. This was my last approach.

```js
function change() {

  var el = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  if (el e == "A Paragraph.") {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
  }
  if (el == "Paragraph changed.") {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "A paragraph.";
  }
```

```html
<h2>Demo JavaScript in Head</h2>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="change()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: `if (el e == "A Paragraph.") {` is invalid syntax. You only need to retrieve the HTML content (or, even better, the `.textContent`), you don't need to access anything further on it to compare the string

Answer (score 0):

The issue is more related to the content and case of the text.

```js
function toggleColor() {

  var el = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  if (el === "A Paragraph.") {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
  }
  if (el === "Paragraph changed.") {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "A Paragraph.";
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Demo JavaScript in Head</h2>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="toggleColor()">Try it</button>
```